# SQL Server (2016) Setup removed permission to drives

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2016, setup

I recently installed a new Sql Server 2016 and selected the root of drive N:\ for transaction logs and drive Z:\ for tempdb. 
In the end the server was succesfully installed and running. But it was not possible to access the drives N or Z anymore.

I suspected Sql Server to expect a folder instead of the whole drive and to change the security settings / permissions on this folder - which in my case was performed on the drive's root and may have caused the symptoms

On the other hand I am pretty sure that I have already sees Sql Server installations using with the root of drives.

Now I wonder if there is a bug in the setup or if it was my fault to configure it that way. And how this can be fixed? Meanwhile IT has modified and opened access to the drives for me, so I can access them now, but Sql Server Service actually is stopped. Do I have to reinstall the sql server or do I have to change all the database's path / log path to a subfolder that has to be created?

Does anyone know what went wrong here?